# Virtual Host configuration, Apache httpd running on non 80 port

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, httpd

I am trying to configure a virtual host on my Windows machine using Apache and HOSTS file combination.

For example, I want `www.example.com` to be served from my server at `localhost`. However, port `80` is taken up by a Citrix process which can't be changed.

So, my `httpd` is running on 81. I want to be able to achieve the following.

1. I hit http://www.example.com on my browser.
2. Apache Virtual Hosts configuration should receive this request despite running on 81. (This is where my worry lies!)
3. Serve pages from http://localhost:81/htdocs.

Is this possible at all?

Following is relevant section in my `httpd.conf`:

```
ServerName www.example.com:81
NameVirtualHost www.example.com:81
```

And my `hosts` file has the below line:

```
127.0.0.1 www.example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Put following snippet in `httpd.conf` and see if it works. It internally forwards all requests to `http://localhost:8080/rat` to `http://localhost:9080/rat`

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so

ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /rat http://localhost:9080/rat
ProxyPassReverse /rat http://localhost:9080/rat
```

URL in browser remains as  `http://www.example.com:8080/rat` but content is served from `http://localhost:9080/rat`

Comment: But what if 8080 is taken by a non-httpd process to which I don't have access?

Comment: If you want httpd to run on different ports you need to listen on different ports and ports must be free .Or there must be two network interfaces. pls see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html#port

Comment: I think what I am trying to do, can't be achieved. I want httpd to run on 81 and yet be able to hit http://www.example.com (80) on my browser. Which is kind of impossible unless I have my httpd listening on both 80 and 81. What do you think?

Comment: yep, I don't doubt so ;) unless there are two network interfaces (= two IP address) and Citrix process is listening on either one, and you could map other IP to apache !

Comment: I have actually figured out how to change Citrix configuration to point to a different port. But, here we logon remotely ONLY to our desktops and I'm afraid I will lose the connection and won't be able to reconnect again if I mess something up. I will live with `www.example.com:81` for now :)